# Loading Data to Cassandra from kafka topic using spring apache kafka

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, cassandra, spring-kafka

I'm trying to develop an spring application which will take input from user and store it to topic and then I wan't to load it to cassandra from this topic (Note:- not using confluent kafka version). SO, far I was able to write a producer and consumer logic in spring and now need to load data from kafka topic to cassandra.
How can I do this??? When I look over internet it was suggested to go with API provided by confluent kafka. But, I would like to do it in Spring. I'm not sure how to code and not sure if I can achieve this with non confluent flavour of apache kafka.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use Kafka Connect with https://github.com/datastax/kafka-sink

Comment: There's no such thing as "Confluent"/"other 'flavors'" of Kafka. Confluent _Platform_ **includes** _**Apache**_ Kafka. If you are referring to Kafka Connect API, that is part of open-source Apache Kafka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is already published on a Kafka topic, you can just use the DataStax [Kafka connector](https://docs.datastax.com/en/kafka/doc/kafka/kafkaIntro.html) for Apache Cassandra, DataStax Enterprise and [Astra DB](https://dtsx.io/2XM1INf).

The connector lets you save records from a Kafka topic to Cassandra tables. It is open-source so it's free to use. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data has a Cassandra Module:

https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-cassandra

> The Apache Cassandra NoSQL Database offers many new capabilities for teams seeking a solution to handle high velocity, high volume and variable data flows. This new way of thinking introduces new concepts and a learning curve that can be intimidating to team members and team managers. Spring Data for Apache Cassandra offers a familiar interface to those who have used other Spring Data modules in the past.

> The learning curve for developing applications with Apache Cassandra is significantly reduced when using Spring Data for Apache Cassandra. With the power to stay at a high level with annotated POJOs, or at a low level with high performance data ingestion capabilities, the Spring Data for Apache Cassandra templates are sure to meet every application need.

Features
Build repositories based on common Spring Data interfaces

- Support for synchronous, reactive, and asynchronous data operations
- Support for XML based Keyspace creation and CQL Table creation
- JavaConfig and XML Support for all Cluster and Session Capabilities
- Exception Translation to the familiar Spring DataAccessException hierarchy
- Convenient QueryBuilders to eliminate the need to learn CQL
- Automatic implementation of Repository interfaces including support for custom query methods
- 2.x versions are based on the 3.x DataStax CQL Java Driver, 3.x versions use DataStax Java Driver 4.x